# What is this warning and how can I fix it?

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, frontend

When I am trying to configure my react app and when I type `yarn add bootstrap@4.0.0` in the command prompt, following warnings come out.

```
C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\React\confusion>yarn add bootstrap@4.0.0
yarn add v1.22.10
warning ..\..\..\..\package.json: No license field
[1/4] Resolving packages...
[2/4] Fetching packages...
info fsevents@2.3.2: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@2.3.2" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
info fsevents@1.2.13: The platform "win32" is incompatible with this module.
info "fsevents@1.2.13" is an optional dependency and failed compatibility check. Excluding it from installation.
[3/4] Linking dependencies...
warning " > @testing-library/user-event@12.8.3" has unmet peer dependency "@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4".
warning "react-scripts > @typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin > tsutils@3.20.0" has unmet peer dependency "typescript@>=2.8.0 || >= 3.2.0-dev || >= 3.3.0-dev || >= 3.4.0-dev || >= 3.5.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-dev || >= 3.6.0-beta || >= 3.7.0-dev || >= 3.7.0-beta".
warning " > bootstrap@4.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "jquery@1.9.1 - 3".
warning " > bootstrap@4.0.0" has unmet peer dependency "popper.js@^1.12.9".
[4/4] Building fresh packages...
success Saved lockfile.
success Saved 1 new dependency.
info Direct dependencies
└─ bootstrap@4.0.0
info All dependencies
└─ bootstrap@4.0.0
Done in 32.72s.

C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\React\confusion>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: I would suggest, besaed upon the clear output, that you can fix it by using compatible modules and by meeting required and/or optional dependencies.

Comment: Seems you are missing peer dependencies `"jquery@1.9.1 - 3"` and `"popper.js@^1.12.9"` (among other missing peer dependencies with `"@testing-library/dom@>=7.21.4"` and `typescript`.

Answer (score 0):

If it is not a licensed project probably you can use -
{ "license": "UNLICENSED" }